# Lua profiler crash as the stack top is null

Tags: iphone, lua, profiling

I am using LuaProfiler, which I have compiled into my iOS app. I am using it in such way:
http://luaprofiler.luaforge.net/manual.html

```
function GameManager:startGame()
    profiler.start( getWritablePath()  .. "GameManager.xxx")
    print("GameManager:startGame()")
    --[[ 
         a lot of code \
    --]]
    profiler.stop()
end
```

I am getting a crash in the profiler because of empty function stack

> function_meter.c: assertion failed: pause_total_time: stack_top null

Am I using profiler in a wrong way?
Maybe it should be compiled with some other parameters, as for now it hase the same as lua interpreter.
What should be changed to make it working, or where I should look for the answer?

Comment: If you remove all the code betwen profiler.start and profiler.stop, does it still crash?

Comment: Could you specify more where does your code crash? Right after start(), somewhere in the middle or near stop() (try adding more debug outputs)? Are you using only a single Lua state, do you use any coroutines?

Comment: @kikito: yes, when I remove code between start and stop it still crashes